# Convert HTML To Canvas

Tags: css, html, canvas, html5-canvas

**Note:** I've tried all relative questions in Stack overflow. But I have not got an answer.

I am trying to convert ***HTML*** To ***Canvas*** . Using either **JavaScript** or **jQuery**.

**JsFiddle Demo is** [here](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/4hb45c8s/2/)

```css
.container {
    width: 500px;
    max-height: 500px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px #292929;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px #292929;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px #292929;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}
.mainbody,
.header,
.footer {
    padding: 5px;
}
.mainbody {
    margin-top: 0;
    min-height: 150px;
    max-height: 388px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.header {
    height: 40px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
    background-color: #ff8080;
    height: 40px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
.footer {
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #b3c6ff;
    border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

section {
    width: 80%;
    height: 200px;   
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
div#one {
    width: 15%;
    height: 200px;
    background: #99ffbb;
    float: left;
}
div#two {
    margin-left: 15%;
    height: 200px;
    background: #ffcccc;
}
```

```html
<b>My HTML Code</b><br>
<div id="MyHTMLCODE">
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        Header
    </div>
    <div class="mainbody">
    My Main Body
       <section>
    <div id="one"> <b>First</b> </div>
    <div id="two"> <b>Second</b> </div>
</section>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        Footer
    </div>
</div>
</div>


<br><b> My Convert Canvas</b><br>
<canvas id="canvas" style="border:2px solid black;" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: html2canvas, that will help

Comment: i tried but not success . plz you can tried to my fiddle

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated earlier, [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) will do this. A minimal example. [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4hb45c8s/1/)

```js
html2canvas($('#MyHTMLCODE'), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        $('#canvas').replaceWith(canvas);
    },
    //width: 200,
    //height: 200
});
```

```css
.container {
    width: 500px;
    max-height: 500px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px #292929;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px #292929;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px #292929;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}
.mainbody,
.header,
.footer {
    padding: 5px;
}
.mainbody {
    margin-top: 0;
    min-height: 150px;
    max-height: 388px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.header {
    height: 40px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
    background-color: #ff8080;
    height: 40px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
.footer {
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #b3c6ff;
    border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

section {
    width: 80%;
    height: 200px;   
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
div#one {
    width: 15%;
    height: 200px;
    background: #99ffbb;
    float: left;
}
div#two {
    margin-left: 15%;
    height: 200px;
    background: #ffcccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
<b>My HTML Code</b><br>
<div id="MyHTMLCODE">
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        Header
    </div>
    <div class="mainbody">
    My Main Body
       <section>
    <div id="one"> <b>First</b> </div>
    <div id="two"> <b>Second</b> </div>
</section>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        Footer
    </div>
</div>
</div>


<br><b> My Convert Canvas</b><br>
<canvas id="canvas" style="border:2px solid black;" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: thank for answer . but footer are not convert into canvas and canvas size small then not result are there

Comment: Remove the fixed width and height options, and it gets the full dimensions without cropping

Comment: i tried your code in fiddle but not result are there . plz try to you fiddle.

Comment: Your fiddle setup has issues with the external resources (use the library from the CDN, not my fiddle)

Comment: And remember to wrap your code within `$(function(){ /* code */ })`